# Array search multiple values in consecutive order

Tags: php, arrays

Take the given arrays:

```
// Original
array:14 [
  0 => "hello"
  1 => "i"
  2 => "like"
  3 => "cats"
  4 => "they're"
  5 => "cute"
  6 => "and"
  7 => "cuddly"
  8 => "you"
  9 => "know"
  10 => "well"
  11 => "i"
  12 => "love"
  13 => "cats"
]

// Sliced
array:6 [
  0 => "like"
  1 => "cats"
  2 => "they're"
  3 => "cute"
  4 => "and"
  5 => "cuddly"
]
```

I want to check the `original` array for my `sliced` values and retrieve their original keys. This must occur only when consecutive values match.

Ultimately, something like:

```
return array_keys_from_consec_values($original, $sliced);

// Result
array:14 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
  2 => 4
  3 => 5
  4 => 6
  5 => 7
]
```

---

### Notes

`sliced` is not a result of using `array_slice()` on the `original` array. Otherwise I would have used that function and utilised the preserve keys parameter.

Want to avoid ambiguities. For example, a simple `array_search` for `cats` would return the key `3`, but `13` also exists. Which might throw the function off.

In the event of any of the `sliced` values not existing in `original` (in order) an empty array should be returned. An example of a `sliced` array that would fail:

```
// Sliced
array:6 [
  0 => "like"
  1 => "cats"
  2 => "they're"
  3 => "cut3"
  4 => "and"
  5 => "cuddly"
]
```

Any recommendations, got speed in mind...

Comment: you mean need only existing in slice?

Comment: I am not clear what you expect in result?

Comment: both are array or string?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by _consecutive value match occurs_? OP you need to be more responsive...

Comment: if all the values in `sliced` exist in `original`, and in order (next to each other and ascending), then return the keys from `original` based on the matched values... check the first part of my question...

Comment: I still don't quite get it check my answer (and update your question with what you have tried so far)

Comment: Is the "sliced" array coming from [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice)? If so, the function has an option to preserve the keys while slicing.

Comment: It's not, see updated.

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: No, I answered my own question. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good effort people, I admit the request was slightly hard to explain - so didn't get exactly what I was looking for. I realised that what I wanted was essentially an `array_search` that returns multiple keys when the needles are found consecutively. I've gone ahead and made the function myself:

```
/**
 * Search for consecutive needles in haystack and return the corresponding keys.
 *
 * @param array $needles => Array values.
 * @param array $haystack => Array to search.
 * @param int $searchDirection => [0] (forwards) | [1] (backwards).
 * @return array
 */
function array_search_all_consec(array $needles, array $haystack, $searchDirection = 0)
{
    $needlesInScope = array_values($needles); // Keys not relevant, reset them.
    $haystackInScope = $haystack;

    if (in_array(reset($needlesInScope), $keys = array_keys($haystackInScope))) {
        $needlesLength = count($needlesInScope);

        foreach (($searchDirection == 0 ? $keys : array_reverse($keys)) as $offset) {
            $length = $offset + $needlesLength;
            $sliced = array_slice($haystackInScope, $offset, $length);

            if (empty(array_diff_assoc($needlesInScope, $sliced))) {
                return range($offset, $length - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return [];
}
```

---

### Test 1

```
$o = [
    0 => "hello",
    1 => "i",
    2 => "like",
    3 => "cats",
    4 => "they",
    5 => "cute",
    6 => "and",
    7 => "cuddly",
    8 => "you",
    9 => "know",
    10 => "well",
    11 => "i",
    12 => "love",
    13 => "cats",
];

$s = [
    "i",
    "love",
    "cats",
];

return array_search_all_consec($s, $o);

// Result
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(11)
  [1] =>
  int(12)
  [2] =>
  int(13)
}
```

---

### Test 2

```
$s = [
    "i",
    "like",
    "cats",
];

return array_search_all_consec($s, $o);

// Result
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [2] =>
  int(3)
}
```

---

### Test 3

```
$s = [
    "i",
    "lov3",
    "cats",
];

return array_search_all_consec($s, $o);

// Result
array(0) {
}
```

---

### Test 4

```
$s = [
    "cats",
    "i",
    "love",
];

return array_search_all_consec($s, $o);

// Result
array(0) {
}
```

---

### Test 5

```
$s = [
    "i",
    "love",
    "cats",
    "blah",
];

return array_search_all_consec($s, $o);

// Result
array(0) {
}
```

---

So there you have it. If anyone can improve the efficiency of the function please do contribute!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to get the index from the `$original` array based on values in `$slice`, you can use the [`array_flip()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and the [`array_unique()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) functions:

```
function array_keys_from_consec_values($original, $slice){
    // Get rid of duplicates and flip the keys with the values
    $index = array_unique($original);
    $index = array_flip($index);

    $result = [];

    // Loop through the slice
    foreach($slice as $key => $value){
        // Check if the value exists in the indexed array
        if(!isset($index[$value])){
            // Return an empty array
            return array();
        }
        // And get the key from the flipped array
        $result[$key] = $index[$value];
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(array_keys_from_consec_values($original, $slice));
```

This will give:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 4
  3 => int 5
  4 => int 6
  5 => int 7
```

Comment: Yeah, that's nearly there, but my biggest problem is dealing with those ambiguities. Really, we want the first occurring `cats` key (`2`). I suppose we could then go ahead and unset it... so we receive the `13` on the next call.

Comment: Think we're on the right track, I'll accept it because it's a good effort and I'll have a further play tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This works on your example data and may be good enough:

```
$r = array_keys(array_unique(array_intersect($o, $s)));
```

If not, since you have a slice:

```
if(($k = array_search($s[0], $o)) === false ||
   array_values($r = array_slice($o, $k, count($s), true)) != $s) {
    $r = [];
}
```

- Find the first key of the original from the first value of the slice
- Slice from the original (preserving keys) and compare to the slice

For your example this yields:

```
Array
(
    [2] => like
    [3] => cats
    [4] => they're
    [5] => cute
    [6] => and
    [7] => cuddly
)
```

I see after the fact that you want to get the keys:

```
$r = array_values(array_flip($r));
```

If the slice is an actual `array_slice` from the original then pass `true` as the forth parameter to preserve the keys.

Comment: Nice, I'll have a play. Array slice if not being used on the original array so that function and its preserve keys parameter cannot be used.